# Converting Date value to a sting that can be used in TestCafe

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm currently using an Excel spreadsheet to store my data for my regression pack when calling the data in testcafe. This was not able to be typed into the field using .typetext as this was a number. I then tried to convert into a string but got the following value: 44416.

How do I allow Testcafe to take in this date from excel and type it into a field?

How about if my date format is 8/20/2021 in excel? Testcafe doesn't seem to like this

1. The "text" argument is expected to be a non-empty string, but it was undefined.

   Browser: Chrome 92.0.4515.131 / Windows 10

   85 |        .click(Selector('a').withText(data.SupervisorName))
   86 |
   87 |        await t
   88 |        .click(staffMembers.startDateField)
   89 |        .pressKey('delete delete delete delete delete delete delete delete delete delete delete')

   > 90 |        .typeText(staffMembers.startDateField, data.StartDate)

Answer (score 2):

Testcafe's `.typeText()` expects date formatted as `yyyy-mm-dd` ([source](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402674/reference/test-api/testcontroller/typetext)).

Depending on the type of the cell the data is in, you might be able to copy it directly from Excel. Excel stores dates as integers, starting from January 1st, 1900. If the cell format is set to `Number`, it will display the 8th of August 2021 as 44416. Set it to `Date` to allow correct copying.

If Excel shows `Date` in a different date format, like `8/20/2021` for example, you'll need to change the format under `Format > More Number Formats` (Or use the `Ctrl + 1` shortcut while having the cells selected), and select `2012-03-14` to choose the correct format.